# Expo publish Error ' should NOT have additional property 'expo'

Tags: expo

how can i resolve this issue, Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/
• should NOT have additional property 'expo'.

this is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MMS",
    "slug": "MMS",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/logocBig.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/logocBig.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "MMS"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/logocBig.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "expo": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    },
    "description": "MMS"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
"expo": {
      "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
    },
```

See [this official doc](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/config/app/), there is no property named 'expo' under the "expo" key in app.json or app.config.json.

Comment: oh my, i though the first expo makes an error, i didn't see other expo there.